# Expose function in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am looking at a rails app and at the top of every controller there is a block of code that looks something like this

```
expose(:var) {Model.find params[:var_id]}
```

I understand what is inside the block just fine but...

I cannot find any documentation on what the expose function does where it comes from or anything I have tried searching the project and using the searchable rails docs.

I would love to know what it does, can someone please tell me or point me to the docs.

Comment: This sounds like a custom, non-rails thing. Have you looked in the application_controller for anything defining `expose`?

Comment: yeah a global search for `def expose` turns up nil

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is probably referencing the `decent_exposure` gem. You can learn more about it here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/259-decent-exposure

Source: https://github.com/voxdolo/decent_exposure

Comment: linking to a 9 minute video isn't an answer

Answer (score 6):

It's a method from the [Decent Exposure](https://github.com/voxdolo/decent_exposure) gem. You can check out a screencast that Ryan Bates did on it over at [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/259-decent-exposure). It's a really great gem. I use it in my application. It cuts down on a lot of the redundancy in the controller layer.

Answer (score 0):

`expose` is not a part of Rails, it comes from the `decent_exposure` gem.

---

It is not an answer to the question. I just want to make the Rails world a bit better and I hope that somebody will read this.

Please think twice before using `expose`. You should only use it if you 100% sure you are using it the right way and it really makes the code better. Read the documentation properly!

One of projects I worked on became unmaintainable because of tons of `expose` in controllers which replaced not only all `@instance_variables` passed to views, but also a lot of business logic and the most helper methods.

When you use `expose` it is not clear in which controller actions and in which views it is used. Unexperienced developers combine data and logic for multiple actions and multiple views in the same `expose` block.
That's a nightmare.

Believe me, `expose` really destroys projects if not used properly.